# why considering the negative values if it bounded between positive values?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

By definition of bounded sequence ($a_n$) is bounded, so there exists $M > 0$ such that $−M ≤ a_n ≤  M $  ,                       for all $n \in N$ . which could be written as $|a_n|≤M$.

My doubt :

suppose I take a sequence $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$ all $n \in N$.

so, According to the definition :  If I take $M = 1$ which happens to be the supremum,  then $−1 ≤\frac{1}{n}≤  1 $

$M=2$, then $−2 ≤\frac{1}{n}≤  2 $.  So on it would be true for other M's greater than 1.

But I know that the sequence is well bounded between $0<\frac{1}{n}≤  1 $.

So why considering the negative values if it bounded between positive values. what concept am I missing? and also why $|a_n|≤M$?

please if you guys could clarify.

Comment: $b_n = -1/n$ is also a bounded sequence, or $c_n = (-1)^n n/(n+1)$ ...

Comment: Not sure to understand the question, but most times the relevant information is that the sequence is bounded, ie $|a_n| < M$ for some $M$. You can have $0 \leq a_n \leq M$, which is indeed more precise, but often, it is sufficient to have $|a_n| < M$ to get useful implications.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. @MartinR So am I think of it like: Since  $-1≤\frac{-1}{n} $ and $\frac{1}{n}≤1$, Hence  $−1 ≤\frac{1}{n}≤  1$ = $|a_n|≤1$

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. @TheSilverDoe. I understand your wording. But I am concerned with the $|a_n|$. which is indicating the negative values which I am not sure about that.

Comment: I don't understand yet what is unclear to you. A sequence of real numbers is bounded if it is bounded below and bounded above, i.e. if there are real numbers $A$ and $B$ such that $A \le a_n \le B$ for all $n$. That is *equivalent* to $|a_n| \le M$ for some real number $M$.